# MVC3 Conditional JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to do some conditional validation using the jQuery validator.

I have a wizard in javascript that calls the validate method when moving to the next step:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();
var anyError = false;

step.find("input").each(function () {
    if (!validator.element(this)) {
        // validate every input
        anyError = true;
    }
});

if (anyError) {
    return false;
}
```

All works fine when I have a [Required] attribute on the model.

However I have this scenario:

- I have a drop down with a choice: Email or Ftp
- When the Email option is selected I want to show the email address field and add validation
- When the Ftp option is selected I don't want to validate the email address

Here's the html snippet for the email address.

```
<div class="email-address" style="display: none;">
   <label class="fullwidth" for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "longtext" })
   <div id="email-validation">
   </div>
```

I've tried all sorts but the next button validation routine always thinks the form is valid. For example.

```
$("form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: '#email-validation',
    rules: {
        EmailAddress: {
           required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        EmailAddress: "Please enter an email address"
    }
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: check this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx
I had the same problem, a dropdown to validate a field, and this article is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but i'm pretty sure you can't use standard jquery-validation in conjunction with MVC3 client-side validation.. You have to do one or the other.

To be more specific, MCV3 client-side validation adapts jquery-validation for it's own use, and this conflicts with using jquery-validation stand-alone.

Comment: No, you are wrong. ASP.NET mvc ships with additional small library that links mvc validation system with jquery validation

Comment: @archil - Yes, i know.  I said that specifically.  The problem is that you can't write generic jquery validation *AND* use the MVC jquery adapters in the same page.

Comment: sorry but that's not true :). mvc built in library just calls jquery-validation plugin methods. They do not conflict. You can use what ever method you like from jquery validation plugin.

Comment: @archil - i've read several people say otherwise, for example: http://blog.waynebrantley.com/2011/01/mvc3-breaks-any-manual-use-of-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the fact that `disabled` inputs do not participate in validation. Add required for server side but just disable and hide EmailAddress when ftp is selected.

Comment: Hi, I've tried disabling the fields and the validation still fails.  Here's the code to call the validator:  var validator = $("form").validate(); var anyError = false;           $step.find("input").each(function () { if (!validator.element(this)) { anyError = true; } }); if (anyError) return false;